# How to include specific hidden file/folder in search result when using telescope.nvim?

Tags: neovim, telescope.nvim

I'm using neovim and Telescope as a finder (find_files, live_grep, file_browser), by default Telescope is ignoring hidden files and files included in .gitignore - how can I add exception (e.g. .gitlab-ci file/folder) to this list? so Telescope will still ignore hidden files except .gitlab-ci file/folder?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use default filter ignore pattern like this:

```lua
telescope.setup {
  ....
  defaults = {
   ....
   file_ignore_patterns = {
     "node_modules", "build", "dist", "yarn.lock"
   },
  }
}
```

I know you can find this in someone's vimrc files or [telescope docs](https://github.com/nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim/blob/master/doc/telescope.txt). But may help some newbies.

Comment: This adds to the file ignore patterns, but is there an inverse? I think that is what the question is asking. If my `.gitignore` includes `private.local.file`, the question is asking how to always include that specific file while continuing to ignore it for git commits.

Comment: For myself, I have a whichkey binding that uses telescope.find_files() with the `search_dirs` and `search_file` flags for files that are commonly ignored but I still want to see.

Answer (score 7):

Telescope uses [`ripgrep`](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) to search through files. By default, `ripgrep` ignores several groups of files, including hidden files (dotfiles) and files ignored by git. Adding `--no-ignore-vcs` and `--hidden` flags will make it to search through those files.

Arguments for `ripgrep` can be configured via `defaults.vimgrep_arguments`.
In your case, to search through hidden files, which are not in `.gitignore` `--hidden` flag should be added:

```lua
require('telescope').setup{
  defaults = {
    vimgrep_arguments = {
      'rg',
      '--color=never',
      '--no-heading',
      '--with-filename',
      '--line-number',
      '--column',
      '--smart-case',
      '--hidden',
    },
}
```

You can always test the command from the terminal before changing the Telescope configuration:

```
rg ... --hidden <search string>
```

As `--hidden` will enable search through **all** hidden files, you might want to look into `.ignore` or `.rgignore` files. They tell `ripgrep` which files to ignore during search. See [`ripgrep`'s documentation](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep/blob/44fb9fce2c1ee1a86c450702ea3ca2952bf6c5a7/GUIDE.md) for more info.

Comment: This is not the answer to the question, but it is the answer that I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

After several weeks of intense reading and testing, I have found the for me easiest solution [here](https://dev.to/waylonwalker/finding-hidden-dotfiles-using-telescope-in-neovim-k9i).

In order to find HIDDEN FILES, I have added the following lines to `.config/nvim/init.vim`:

```
nnoremap fff <cmd>Telescope find_files <cr>
nnoremap ffh <cmd>Telescope find_files hidden=true<cr>
```

When you launch Neovim UI, pressing `fff` pops up the Telescope `find_file` screen, and when you press `ffh`, you can search for HIDDEN files.

To search for hidden files in `LIVE_GREP`, the work was a bit more difficult.

From my perspective, the most elegant solution is to first create the following `.config/nvim/lua/find_hidden.lua`:

```lua
local telescope = require("telescope")
local telescopeConfig = require("telescope.config")

-- Clone the default Telescope configuration
local vimgrep_arguments = { unpack(telescopeConfig.values.vimgrep_arguments) }

-- I want to search in hidden/dot files.
table.insert(vimgrep_arguments, "--hidden")
-- I don't want to search in the `.git` directory.
table.insert(vimgrep_arguments, "--glob")
table.insert(vimgrep_arguments, "!**/.git/*")

telescope.setup({
  defaults = {
    -- `hidden = true` is not supported in text grep commands.
        hidden = true,
    vimgrep_arguments = vimgrep_arguments,
  },
  pickers = {
    find_files= {
            hidden = true,
      -- `hidden = true` will still show the inside of `.git/` as it's not `.gitignore`d.
      find_command = { "rg", "--files", "--hidden", "--glob", "!**/.git/*" },
    },
   },
})
----- This activates the search for hidden files in live_grep
require("telescope").setup {
     pickers = {
          live_grep = {
             additional_args = function(_ts)
                 return {"--hidden"}
             end
          },
     },
  }
```

The add the following the following lines to your `init.vim`:

```
:lua require('find_hidden')
nnoremap gre <cmd>Telescope live_grep <cr>
```

To sum it up: with the `find_hidden.lua` file and the following lines in your `init.vim`, you can easily search for hidden and non-hidden files both in `telescope_find_files` and `telescope_live_grep`:

```
:lua require('find_hidden')

nnoremap fff <cmd>Telescope find_files <cr>
nnoremap ffh <cmd>Telescope find_files hidden=true<cr>
nnoremap gre <cmd>Telescope live_grep <cr>
```

Answer (score 3):

I was also searching for a configuration that would allow me to search for/in hidden files while using telescope plugin. The core of solution is to use [`ripgrep`](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) with `-g / --glob` parameter.

> Info: When using `ripgrep` in telesope, ripgreps will respects your `.gitignore` while searching - [reference](https://github.com/nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim#file-pickers)

The simple config that allowed me this, looks like following:

```lua
require('telescope').setup({
  defaults = {
    -- configure to use ripgrep
    vimgrep_arguments = {
      "rg",
      "--follow",        -- Follow symbolic links
      "--hidden",        -- Search for hidden files
      "--no-heading",    -- Don't group matches by each file
      "--with-filename", -- Print the file path with the matched lines
      "--line-number",   -- Show line numbers
      "--column",        -- Show column numbers
      "--smart-case",    -- Smart case search

      -- Exclude some patterns from search
      "--glob=!**/.git/*",
      "--glob=!**/.idea/*",
      "--glob=!**/.vscode/*",
      "--glob=!**/build/*",
      "--glob=!**/dist/*",
      "--glob=!**/yarn.lock",
      "--glob=!**/package-lock.json",
    },

    ...
 
  },
  pickers = {
    find_files = {
      hidden = true,
      -- needed to exclude some files & dirs from general search
      -- when not included or specified in .gitignore
      find_command = {
        "rg",
        "--files",
        "--hidden",
        "--glob=!**/.git/*",
        "--glob=!**/.idea/*",
        "--glob=!**/.vscode/*",
        "--glob=!**/build/*",
        "--glob=!**/dist/*",
        "--glob=!**/yarn.lock",
        "--glob=!**/package-lock.json",
      },
    },
  },
})
```

Comment: `pickers` should be outside `defaults`, like this:

```require('telescope').setup {
    defaults = {
        ...
    },

    pickers = {
        find_files = {
            find_command = {
                "rg",
                "--files",
                "--hidden",
            },
        },
    },
}```

Comment: Yes @invis, you're right. Thanks, I've already updated the example!

Answer (score 1):

After much pain and suffering, I've read the `telescope.txt` help and maanged to show hidden files in both `find_files` and `live_grep`:

### find_files

When running `find_files`, use the `no_ignore` option, available in Vimscript  ([help](https://github.com/nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim/blob/a19770625aed49ad2a9f591a5e3946707f7359f6/doc/telescope.txt#L884)).

```
:Telescope find_files no_ignore=true
```

### live_grep

But for `live_grep` we need to pass the `additional_args` option which is (correct me if I'm wrong) only available in Lua ([help](https://github.com/nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim/blob/a19770625aed49ad2a9f591a5e3946707f7359f6/doc/telescope.txt#L814)).

```lua
require('telescope.builtin').live_grep({ additional_args = { '-u' } })
```

The `-u` flag is an `rg` flag that shows ignored files.

### Some notes

I guess you can affect these in the settings, if someone comments that for both I'll add them to my answer.

I, personally, need to have a keymap for each, so here's my `lazy.nvim` keys config:

```lua
  keys = {
    -- this one is double space by default in LazyVim, uncomment if necessary
    -- { "<leader>fi", "<cmd>Telescope find_files<cr>", desc = "Telescope Files" }, 
    { "<leader>fh", "<cmd>Telescope find_files no_ignore=true<cr>", desc = "Telescope Files Hidden" },
    { "<leader>hi", "<cmd>Telescope oldfiles<cr>", desc = "Telescope Old" },
    { "<leader>ag", "<cmd>Telescope live_grep<cr>", desc = "Telescope Grep" },
    {
      "<leader>ah",
      function()
        require("telescope.builtin").live_grep({ additional_args = { "-u" } })
      end,
      desc = "Telescope Grep Hidden",
    },
  },
```

I wished interfaces that dealt with file filters would let you specify these:

- ***god globs***: a glob that when matched is **always** included.
- ***ignore ignore***: ignore a specific ignore file, such as a .gitignore.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to use a `.ignore` file. According to the [docs](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep/blob/master/GUIDE.md#automatic-filtering), you can create rules that ignore the ripgrep defaults. I have a git repo full of hidden files that I would like to include in the search results, so the `.ignore` looks like this:

```
!*
.git/
```

First, I include all the files in the repo. Then I remove the `.git` directory again. Now all my dot files are shown in Telescope.